# Plotting a transparency patch on octave

Tags: plot, octave, transparency, patch

I made a plot on octave and to put on evidence a specific region of the plot I want to put over a rectangle or patch e.g. yellow but transparent in order to see the plot behind.
I googled but I didn't find a solution.
Please, could you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a rectangle object, and reach into its properties to set its child's transparency.

```
X = [0:0.1:10];
p = plot( X, 3 * sin(X) + X )
grid on
r = rectangle('position', [3, 1, 3, 3], 'curvature', 0.25, 'edgecolor','k', 'facecolor', 'y' )
set( get(r, 'children'), 'facealpha', 0.25 )
```

[image]

Comment: PS. Hint: check out the `lookfor` function in octave. E.g. try `lookfor rectangle`.

Comment: Thank you Tasos for your answer and the code. But the rectangle is not transparent. If you add the command "grid on", you do not see the grid under the rectangle.

Comment: I have found a way to make the rectangle transparent; answer updated.

Comment: Hi Tasos.I do not obtain your result. Running your code, at the end the rectangle is transparent but not colored. Could be the version of Octave: I have the 4.2.2 (2018-03-13). Your is the same or not?. Thank you for your support.

Comment: Using last version of octave (4.4.1) the solution proposed by Tasos works and also the variant of  putting in the command rectangle the property 'facealpaha' and the value 0.25. What now does not work is the creation of a picture. I used a lot of format but the result is always the rectangle opaque. A workaround is make a print screen (ctrl + alt + prn.scr) open paint put the image into paint and select only the picture and save in format png, jpg, etc.

Comment: this depends partly on the print driver used and whether it supposers transparency (and whether you pass the right options). You'll have to play around a bit. the 'svg' driver supports the transparency out the box from what I've tested just now. Worse case scenario create an svg and then use imagemagick separately to convert it to your preferred format or something.

Comment: Perfect. I create a functon that make the svg file and than convert in png by mean of imagemagic. Thank you very much

Comment: @arkkimede glad to help. Proper transparency should be supported in the near future for more printer drivers, but in the meantime this is a decent workaround. Make sure your svg is large enough / line thicknesses are big enough, to capture all relevant details upon conversion to a png etc. Also, please mark this answer as correct if it adequately answers your question.

Comment: I'm not able to mark the answer as correct but, YES, your answer is correct and adequately you solve my question. PS Please suggest me how to procede for to mark the answer

Comment: @arkkimede Marking an answer simply involves ticking the green tick; its purpose is to help future users quickly find questions with accepted answers. On the other hand, if you meant you don't feel fully satisfied by the answer to accept it, that's totally fine. Though, for future reference, please try not to 'escalate' your question in the comments, as this then confuses the issue of when a question has been adequately answered (e.g. 'how to print in a way that respects figure transparency' is effectively a different problem; I'd argue that the original question has been answered as asked )